# Hover an anchor tag using SASS (not SCSS)

Tags: css, sass, hover

I am trying to learn SASS (not SCSS) and I am following their documentation, but the `&hover` is not working.

SASS:

```
a
  color: red
  &:hover
    color: green
```

The generated CSS and HTML:

```css
a {
  color: red; }
  a:hover {
    color: green; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated CSS?

Comment: Yes, it looks perfect:

a {
  color: red; }
  a:hover {
    color: green; }

Comment: Then why do you think it's not working? Look at the snippet I've just inserted; the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Even the cursor pointer isn't working. I've been doing this way for quite a long time and never had this problem before, just now, coincidentally that I am using SASS

Comment: What do you mean *"even the cursor pointer"*? It's unclear what you think the problem is, that snippet behaves exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: PS: Isn't working on Chrome or any other of my browsers, however it works here on the Code snippet

Comment: Then the code you've provided isn't a [mcve], so this question is unanswerable. As far as I can tell, SASS is working just fine and the result does what you say you want.

Comment: When I change the font color on my SASS code, the browser receives it, and works perfectly. However, the hover doesn't work, and the anchor tags are not having the pointer cursor. The link to the CSS file is correct on my HTML head (the style for all other items are working correctly).

Comment: We're going around in circles, so I won't respond further. I'm saying that **what you've posted** doesn't indicate any problem at all. If you can come up with an example that *does*, [edit] it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I am going to put here the complete code, and explain in a different way, maybe it will help you to help me.

The behaviour of my  tags are not working properly in any of my browsers. No errors on my console as well.

Here's the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>SASS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Hi this is a test</h1>
  </header>

<article>
  <h2><a href="">about me</a></h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit possimus ducimus delectus, quod, itaque odio nostrum molestiae, reiciendis ipsum nobis nihil, placeat excepturi repudiandae aspernatur enim quisquam dicta fuga! Corrupti!</p>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</article>

<footer>
  <p>copyright 2018 jorge</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the SASS document:

```
//SASS

// VARIABLES

$black:  #333
$pale:  #d2e1dd
$pink:  #c69
$blue:  #036

$font-stack:  'Andale Mono', monospace
$font-size:  14px

// MIXINS
=circleThing($rad, $height, $width, $bg, $color)
  -webkit-border-radius: $rad
  -moz-border-radius: $rad
  -ms-border-radius: $rad
  -o-border-radius: $rad
  border-radius: $rad

  height: $height
  width: $width

  line-height: $height
  text-align: center

  background: $bg
  color: $color
  margin: 0 auto


// STYLES


body
  background: $pale
  color: $black
  font-family: $font-stack
  font-size: $font-size

article
  background: white
  width: 760px
  margin: -60px auto
  padding: 40px
  box-sizing: border-box
  position: relative
  z-index: -2

a
  color: red
  &:hover
    color: green


header
  +circleThing(100%, 200px, 200px, $blue, white)
  h1
    font-size: $font-size + 2

footer
  +circleThing(100%, 150px, 150px, $black, $pale)
  font-size: $font-size - 3
  position: relative
  z-index: -4
  margin-top: -60px
```

This SASS is generating the CSS as below:

```
body {
  background: #d2e1dd;
  font-family: "Andale Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 14px; }

article {
  background: white;
  width: 760px;
  margin: -60px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2; }

a {
  color: red; }
  a:hover {
    color: green; }

header {
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #036;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 16px; }

footer {
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #d2e1dd;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -4;
  margin-top: -60px; }
```

The problem is: When I open this index file on my browser (either Chrome and Firefox) the  tags does not change its color when hover, and even the cursor is not changing for a pointer. All the other elements are working perfectly, only the anchor tags have this issue. It seems to work correctly on code snippet, but I have no idea what is wrong, since the generated css looks correct.

I Changed my  tag to another CSS (normal css) file, just to test, and it worked perfectly.